# JQuery Making Code Reusable On Same Page

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I created a form and wrote all the JQuery for it -- form validation etc. Everything works nice but I'd like to learn how I can make this JQuery reusable so I can have more than one form on a page and still have everything work properly. Right now, when I submit one form, the JQuery executes and validates all the forms not just the one I submit.

Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't help. But, essentially, you'd need to make your current script a function to which you pass the element you wish to validate, or a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Can we see a live page or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("form").each(function(){
    $(this).validate();
});
```

This will run validation for each individual form on your page.

You can also do this (but I don't recommend inline Javascript):

```
function validate(){
    $(this).validate();
}
```

Then on each of your forms:

```
<form onsubmit="validate();">
```

**EDIT:** If you're not using the validate plugin, then try this:

```
$("form").each(function(){
    $(this).submit(function(){
        // your validation code here
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/ZSejr/).

Comment: Is validate() a jquery function or for the validate plugin?

Comment: Yes, I was under the impression you were using it. If not, just replace `$(this).validate();` with `$(this).submit(function(){ /* your validation here */ });`